# Template or Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, stl

Which one do you prefer more:

```
template <class STRATEGY>
class A
{
  STRATEGY *m_pMyStrategy; // User has to create new strategy class
// class A needs to use traits 
// or some other means to decide if strategy meets the requirements

};
```

or

```
class A
{
  IBaseStrategy *m_pMyStrategy; // User inherits IBaseStrategy class
};
```

Why does std::vector choose the first one for allocator ?

Comment: the whole std collection is focused on template rather than inheritance.

Comment: Look up run time and compile time polymorphism.

Comment: I probably wouldn't ask a 'which do you prefer?' question on here since it's left to the programmer to interpret if one implementation is more preferable to another if both complete the same task.

Comment: Both snippets are pretty terrible.

Comment: I think the standards committee admitted the way `std::vector` handles allocators was a mistaken design.

Comment: @T.C.: I don't know why you feel the snippets are terrible... I am assuming that is because you feel the code snippets are out of context, and don't provide enough info to give answer to the question... I added std::vector and allocator for that purpose... anyways, I am rephrasing the question a little...

Comment: Well, now you've just turned a question asking for opinions with a historical/design side-question into a primarily historical/design question. Unfortunately, this means that the votes cast (including close votes) and Jerry Coffin's answer are quite inadequate now. I'm not sure if you should ask a new question instead, if you really want to know specifically about `std::vector`'s design. (If in doubt, ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) how to proceed with this question.)

Comment: @T.C.: I reverted back to the original question, to keep the original question's asnwer valid, as per dyp suggestion... feel free to suggest how this question can be improved... unless your suggestion is to delete it, which i don't want to do, as it already contains an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What most of us would probably prefer (will probably prefer, when it becomes available) is to use some sort of concepts so we can have our cake and eat it too (so to speak): pass the `STRATEGY` as a template parameter, but also specify the requirements that the `STRATEGY` needs to meet.

Your second (inheritance-based) version causes a fundamental problem: although it makes it easy to specify the interface the client class needs from the strategy class, it requires that the author of the strategy class be aware of the name of the base class for strategies when he's writing the strategy class.

In other words, it's not enough that the strategy class provides the right interface--it needs to inherit from the right base class to inform the compiler of the fact that it's providing that particular interface.

This gets particularly clumsy in large projects--you need a great deal of cross-project coordination to ensure that all the interfaces people are going to require are designed and known ahead of time, so everybody who's going to provide a strategy class knows what to use as a base class when they define their class.

Concepts reduce the level of communication necessary, because rather than requiring that a strategy inherit from a specified base class to show that it implements a particular interface, the client class can directly specify the interface it requires, and any strategy class that meets those requirements can be used. If two different client classes in different parts of the code both want to use similar strategies, they don't have to coordinate first to (for example) agree on the name for the base class of the strategy they'll accept--rather, each just specifies the interface it requires, and any class that meets the requirements of that interface can be used for that role (even if its author never even heard of the name they choose for the interface, not to mention used it as a base class).

For now, imitating concepts with a combination of traits and something like `static_assert` is probably about the best we can do. The code is often ugly and clumsy, but at least it gets the fundamentals correct--in particular, it puts the responsibility in the right places.

Since the "responsibility in the right places" part probably isn't clear, I mean the person writing the strategy class only needs to take responsibility for providing the right interface, *not* for basically guessing correctly at what name (for example) the client classes might choose to give for a base class they define to specify the interface they want. It also means that both the client and the server sides (or whatever you prefer to call them) both concern themselves with functionality more than inventing names, and having others guess the names correctly.